# A case of vacuous truth : Have you taken part in your department's open discussion session already?

Tags: logic

Today I encountered a vacuously true case. But I am not so sure, so please help examine it.

It was from a question form that asks:

> Have you taken part in your department's open discussion session already?

And below the question, there were a "yes" and "no" boxes for me to check.

---

**I think both the "yes" and "no" are vacuously true in my case, and why I think like that:**

First of all, there aren't any open discussion sessions from my department.

According to Wikipedia's explanation about the subject,

[image: x]

The set of my department's open discussion session is empty, so I conclude that both the "yes" and "no" are vacuously true in my case, and that I could've in fact checked both boxes.

I am not an experienced logic or philosophy learner, so I am not sure if my understanding and deduction is correct.

Would you guys help me out?

---

**The following part was posted on 09/04 2020 to further explain my question**

Here is a more detailed process of my understanding of this case.

Step 1

> The "yes" means "I have taken part in my department's open discussion session already."

Step 2

> The "no" means "I have not taken part in my department's open discussion session already."

Step 3

> Given that there are no open discussion sessions from my department, both the "yes" and "no" are true because the set of "my department's open discussion" has no representatives.

which is also mentioned on the Wikipedia page.

[image]

A case mentioned in Wikipedia, it says "All the cell phones in the room are turned off" and "All the cell phones in the room are turned on" are both true when there are no cell phones in the room.

Another case mentioned in Wikipedia tells us that "I ate every vegetable on my plate" is true, when there were no vegetables on the plate to begin with.

The Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

So, I wonder whether both "yes" and "no" are true. But I am not confident in my understanding and deduction.

Hope you guys would help me examine the case.

Comment: As is, the question is ambiguous and that is why it seems that both truth values obtain, but, in fact, ambiguous questions are ill-posed and have no answer. In practice, ambiguities are resolved by context. Translated into the predicate calculus to eliminate the ambiguity the sentence looks like this: ∃x(D(x) Λ P(I,x)) (there is something which is today's discussion session and I participated in it). Since there was no discussion session the sentence is false and the answer to the (disambiguated)  question is no. It is not yes, and it is not vacuous, there is no implication involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really a case of vacuous truth; it's a matter of the pragmatics of language. It is similar to the classic, "Have you stopped beating your wife?" The question makes an incorrect assumption, so in the event that you never started and hence never stopped beating your wife, to answer 'no' is true but potentially misleading.

If your department has had no open discussion sessions then *a fortiori* you have not participated in any, so the correct answer is 'no'. But it is understandable that you are reluctant to check 'no' since this gives the misleading impression that such sessions occurred and you declined to take part. If the question had been worded, "Have you taken part in every open discussion session that your department has held?" then a 'yes' answer might qualify as vacuously true.

Comment: "*answer 'no' is true but potentially misleading*" How could a true answer be at all misleading?

Comment: @Speakpigeon The same way the second law of thermodynamics in pop-sci is true but misleading, people are likely to misinterpret it.

Comment: @Conifold Good to know. So, it is true that you stopped betting your wife. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Because language has more that fifty shades of grey and the truth value does not at all determine the meaning.

Comment: True statements can easily mislead and often do. A statement can be a partial truth, or it can obscure a truth by providing too much information, or it can play on a known false belief of the audience, or it can invite an incorrect inference. The theory of conversational implicature is concerned with explaining how pragmatic features of language allow true statements to avoid being misleading or inappropriate.

Comment: But a "yes" means "I have taken part in my department's open discussion session already." And "no" means "I have not taken part in my department's open discussion session already." But there are no such things like that from my department. Doesn't that make both "yes" and "no" true? A case mentioned in Wikipedia, it says "All the cell phones in the room are turned off" and "All the cell phones in the room are turned on" are both true when there are no cell phones in the room. The source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking  Klöcking? Wait, that reminds me of something... Ah, yes, the brave new world "*moderator*" who decided for no good reason that my post was worse being deleted, and so he just deleted my post. That was 27 days ago, it says on the tin: "**This post is hidden. It was deleted 27 days ago by Philip Klöcking**". And you expect what now, that we could have a nice conversation? Reinstate my post first and apologise.

Comment: @Bumble So, it is true that you stopped betting your wife.

Comment: @Speakpigeon We don't need your sarcasm here. And I will not apologise for rightfully handling a flag in the way I did.

Comment: @vincentin The examples you quote from Wikipedia are all universal claims. All P's are Q's. All the cell phones are turned on. These are trivially true if there are no P's or if there are no cell phones. But your example is an existential claim: it translates as "does there exist an event which consists of you participating in an open discussion session?" The answer to that is no. There were none, so you took part in none. If the question had been worded, "have you partipated in every open discussion session?" that would be a universal and could be deemed trivially true.

Comment: @Speakpigeon No. If you read my answer carefully, I say the opposite. It is not true that I have stopped beating my wife for the simple reason that I never started. However, for me to say, "I have not stopped beating my wife" could be misleading because it might give the impression that I am in the habit of beating her and continue to do so.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Rightfully? My answer was relevant to the question and it was 100% truthful. So, how come you could rightfully delete it? Please explain yourself if you can.

Comment: @Bumble Sorry, I did misread your answer. You are absolutely correct, my bad.I cannot remove the down vote but that's because of the rest of your answer.

Comment: @Speakpigeon The answer is 90+% tangential rant and even the examples given are simply stated to be valid without explanation, which fits with the answer as a whole as it is not substantiated in any way and could just as well be opinion. If you have any problem with that, you can always appeal via flags or the 'contact team' button. Now that's enough off-topic commenting. Chat and Meta are open for discussing things like that.

Comment: @Bumble Ok, it makes sense if it translates as the meaning you said. Thank you.

Comment: @Bumble Let's forget the question form. If we only focus on these two expressions: "I have taken part in my department's open discussion session already" and "I have not taken part in my department's open discussion session already" and with my department not having any discussion sessions, don't we just have two statements that are vacuously true? According to the wikipedia page, as long as the set we refer to is empty, a statement dealing with that set is true, no matter what that statement is, is my understanding correct? I don't know why it has to be a universal claim to be vacuously true.

Comment: Universals can be trivially true because in modern logic they are understood hypothetically. All P's are Q's is taken to mean that for any x, if x is a P then x is a Q. Hence if there are no P's this comes out true. But a claim about a specific P would come out false. So, if there are no mobile phones, "all mobile phones are switched on" is true. But, "I made a call on my mobile phone" is false. The latter is an existential claim: it means there exists a thing that is my mobile phone and I made a call on it, and this is false.

Comment: Thank you. I am starting to grasp the idea more and more.
I realized my affirmative sentence (the first one) is false just like these statements "Yesterday, I went to the Land of Oz" or "I have been to Atlantis", which are 100% false.
By the way, "I have not taken part in my department's open discussion sessions already" is also false, right? because it translates to "there exists a discussion session of my department and I have not taken part in it already" which is not the case due to the lack of a discussion like that.

Comment: I would go along with that. Russell agrees too, so you are in good company. Russell's examples are "the present king of France is bald" and "the present king of France is not bald". Both are false according to Russell because they should be understood to mean there exists one and only one thing that is the present king of France and that thing is bald (or not bald).

Answer (score -1):

On the notion of "vacuously true", it is a novelty introduced in mathematical logic. In logical terms, its operational value is zero. That is to say, the truth value of a "vacuously true" proposition  is "true", not "vacuously true". In "classical" mathematical logic, there are only two truth values, and there is no room to accommodate "vacuous truth" as a third truth value. Further, the logical calculus does not depend on whether a proposition is "vacuously" true. The result of a logical operation is exactly the same whether a proposition is true or "vacuously true". In other words, "vacuously true" is a dummy. A vacuous truth value.

So, why bother with the dummy?

Very simple. In "classical" mathematical logic, a logical implication φ → ψ is true if the antecedent φ is false. This notion is of course abhorrent, and it is abhorrent because it is obviously false. Mathematicians are most of them adamant that this is nonetheless correct, but there is constant denigration and calling  "vacuously true" any implication with a false antecedent at least goes some way towards alleviating the pressure. It provides psychological relief.

This is not the only example of mathematical logic toying with the lexicon of logic: not only "vacuous" truth, but "validity", "tautology", "material" implication... and more.

Yet, in this particular case, I guess the official answer is not "vacuous truth", but straightforward falsity. The justification is that the question implicitly assumes the existence of something that doesn't in fact exist, like saying "God loves you", or, to use Bertrand Russell's quaint example, "The king of France is bald": The king of France can neither be bald or not be bald because he doesn't exist.

Of course, it is not apparent that it is a proper logical explanation, but this is all that mathematicians can say in this case, and if not, then I'll be happy to be corrected.

Comment: If you weren't so focused on your crusade against the material conditionals you'd notice that this particular case does not even involve a conditional. The Russell's paraphrase of "The current king of France is bald" is "There is someone who is the current king of France and he is bald".

Comment: @Conifold 1. It is apparent that I "*notice that this particular case does not even involve a conditional*".My answer has two parts. The first part is about "vacuous truth", which is the main point, and vacuous truth only concerns the so-called "material" *implication*. The second part concerns false assumptions. 2. You are so myopic that you don't even realise that your own interpretation falsifies your explanation.

Comment: In other words, the first part of your post should be deleted, and replaced with "this is not a case of vacuous truth because implication is not involved". That would make it much clearer.

Comment: @Conifold But the question is explicitly about "vacuous truth" and it is right and proper that I should answer the question. Also, you could not prove that no implication is involved. It is what you want believe but you contradicted yourself in this respect.

Comment: It does not ask about it, it asserts (erroneously) that it is the case here. And if you are going on excursion about it then, at least, do not make things up to match your pet preconceptions. "Vacuous" as in empty of substance is a colloquial expression, not a novelty introduced by mathematical logic, and is used there in informal commentary in that very sense. And I doubt that you can point to anything backing up your "abhorrent" or "psychological relief" other than your own armchair musings.

Comment: A "yes" means "I have taken part in my department's open discussion session already." And a "no" means "I have not taken part in my department's open discussion session already." But there are no such things like that from my department. Doesn't that make both "yes" and "no" true so that I can in fact check both boxes? A case mentioned in Wikipedia, wiki says "All the cell phones in the room are turned off" and "All the cell phones in the room are turned on" are both true when there are no cell phones in the room. The source: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Comment: @Conifold Whatever you personally doubt from the vantage point of your own armchair is irrelevant to what I do and to whether what I say here is true or not. The fact is that "vacuous truth" is not a truth value and has therefore no operational value in two-valued logic. And thus there is zero reason to introduce this notion, and yet it is part of the discourse mathematicians have developed around the material implication. It is a sop. Full stop.

Comment: It is not introduced as a truth value, an implication is said to be vacuously true when its premise is false. As such, it is a perfectly well-defined shorthand. The reason for using it is to emphasize the difference between the material and colloquial conditionals, which is perfectly legitimate when teaching those used to the latter.

Comment: @Conifold This might have merit if mathematical logic textbooks emphasised how much the material implication is not even an implication..

Comment: They do so profusely in the opening chapters, stressing how it does not presuppose causation or any other substantive connection between premise and conclusion, as in colloquial "implication". Indeed, "material conditional" is more commonly used.

Comment: @Conifold Remind me where it is that Aristotle says that a syllogism "presupposed" causation. As for "substantive connection", I am not sure what you mean. The fact that Aristotle was happy to use letters to represent propositions suggests he understood validity as a matter of form rather than of substance. I myself posted an answer which clearly makes validity a question of form, including in the case of an informal  argument, which is valid only if the appropriate definitions are assumed.

Comment: @Conifold Why is a material implication called implication if mathematicians thinks it is not an implication?

Comment: @Conifold Why is the material implication used by mathematicians to prove that some axioms or theorems imply other theorems?.

Comment: Mathematicians do not think that "implication" has any definite meaning. Neither colloquial use nor Aristotle are particularly cogent, but relevantist interpretations of Aristotle is what I meant by "substantive connection". It was Philo the Dialectician, not mathematicians, who introduced the material conditional as a definite version c. 300 BC. As for its use by them, here is Peirce:"*I wish to reason so that facts shall not, and cannot, disappoint the promises of my reasoning. Whether such reasoning is agreeable to my intellectual impulses is a matter of no sort of consequence*".

Comment: @Conifold Contradiction between "*Mathematicians do not think that "implication" has any definite meaning*" and Pierce.Also, Aristotle's syllogistic and "colloquial" is a cogent as anything can be. Mathematicians adopt the material implication only because they are incapable of making sense of the logical implication.They are incompetent logicians. If they believed the implication has no meaning, they would not say Aristotle committed the *existential fallacy*. If you want to know the meaning mathematicians give to the implication, read Irving M. Copi's Introduction to logic.

Comment: What contradiction? Colloquial meaning, even more cogent than this one, and what happens to work are two different things. Being false when the premise is true but conclusion is false is exactly what the non-disappointment of inferred promises requires. Existential import is a convention that changes only phrasing, doing with it as one pleases isn't a fallacy. The rest is made up to fit your personal sentiment.